# Python OpenCV Find License Plate

Tags: python, opencv, edge-detection

I'm trying to find a license plate in an image. I'm preprocessing the image (convert to HSV, filter by color etc.). I use the result in a function called "detect_plate" where I'm using a canny edge detection and then trying to find the plate by filtering the contours with 4 corner points.

From my preprocessed image I would guess that this should work, but somehow the license plate is not found. Here is my code and my example image:

```
def detect_plate(image, lower=0, upper=20):
    
    image_contours = image.copy()
    blur = cv2.medianBlur(image_contours,3)
    edges = cv2.Canny(blur.copy(), lower, upper)
    edges_3_channel = cv2.cvtColor(edges, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)
    #cv2.drawContours(image_contours, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
    plate = []
    for cont in contours:
        peri = cv2.arcLength(cont, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cont, 0.018*peri, True)
        if len(approx) == 4:
            plate.append(approx)
            break
    if plate: 
        cv2.drawContours(image_contours, plate, -1, (0,255,0), 3)

    output = np.concatenate([edges_3_channel, image_contours], axis=1)

    output = cv2.resize(output, (int(output.shape[1]*0.6), int(output.shape[0]*0.6)))
    return output
```

[image]

Any suggestions how to improve my code?

Comment: Hello, obviously, your contours are not enough shaped, try use 0.01 factor instead of 0.018.
Be sure of image resolution you use, if there is som exmaples, first be sure algorithm works on examples before trying new ones.

Comment: What is the benefit of edge detection when you have a so clearly segmented plate ?